# Collect sub-elements in a json object python

Tags: python, json

So essentially I have a JSON object obtained through an API that looks similar to the one below and I am wondering how I would collect the sub-elements such as name and quantity and place it into an array/list.

```
{
   "item_one": {
      "name": "Item One",
      "weight": 0,
      "quantity": 1
   },
   "item_two": {
      "name": "Item Two",
      "weight": 0,
      "quantity": 23
   },
   "item_three": {
      "name": "Item Three",
      "weight": 0,
      "quantity": 53
   }
}
```

An example for what the desired output is would be the following:

```
nameLst = ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three']
quantityLst = ['1', '23', '53']
```

So far the only way I know how to do this would be to individually collect the quantity and name data by searching through all the specific items, this however would be impossible due to the sheer number of potential items.

Comment: "this however would be impossible due to the sheer number of potential items" - Why would the number make that impossible?

Comment: @KellyBundy well there is something like 1000 possible items and I am not going to code in the individual names for all of them, it isn't impossible but it isn't something I would be willing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know the item names, you can simply loop over the *keys* of the dictionary and use those keys to query the JSON blob for each subdict.

```
namelst = []
quantitylst = []

for key in d.keys():
    subdict = d[key]
    namelst.append(subdict["name"])
    quantitylst.append(subdict["quantity"])
```

If you don't need the *keys* at any point, then you can loop over the *values* solely as Kelly Bundy mentions.

```
for v in d.values():
    namelst.append(v["name"])
    quantitylst.append(v["quantity"])
```

Answer (score 0):

> So far the only way I know how to do this would be to individually collect the quantity and name data by searching through all the specific items, this however would be impossible due to the sheer number of potential items.

I imagine you're just saying that this would be hard to do by hand, and you could do something like this.

```
distinct_keys = {k for d in json_obj.values() for k in d}

# you seem to want to convert ints to strings?
# if so, consider (some_transform(d[k]) if k in d else None)
result = {k:[d.get(k, None) for d in json_obj.values()] for k in distinct_keys}
```

If you actually need to iterate through this thing one object at a time though, consider something like the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in json_obj.values():
    # if you KNOW you don't have missing data
    # for k,v in d.items(): result[k].append(v)

    # you probably do have missing data though, so a cost proportional
    # to your key sizes is unavoidable starting from completely unprocessed
    # json data. you could save a little work, but here's the basic idea

    # the work we do is different based on which sets/maps have they
    # keys we're operating on
    s = set(d.keys())
    new_keys = s.difference(result)
    missing_keys = [k for k in result if k not in s]
    same_keys = s.intersection(result)

    # this doesn't necessarily have to be special cased, but it
    # allows us to guarantee result is non-empty everywhere else
    # and avoid some more special casing.
    if new_keys and not result:
        for k,v in d.items():
            result[k].append(v)
    else:
        # backfill new keys we found with None
        L = result[next(iter(result))]
        for key in new_keys:
            result[key] = [None]*len(L)
            result[key].append(d[key])

        # fill in None for the current object for any keys in result
        # that we don't have available
        for key in missing_keys:
            result[key].append(None)

        # for everything in both objects, just append the new data
        for key in same_keys:
            result[key].append(d[key])
```

Then if you really needed variables and not a dictionary you can explicitly store them that way.

```
for k,L in result.items():
    globals()[f'{k}Lst'] = L
```

Comment: Sorry about the error -- fixed now. As for the keys/_/items point, I changed it (the style was out of habit since I do normally need the key and value), but I don't think it was a huge deal either way.